# In Java - what type of pane or swing / fx object would I use to emulate the pane OneNote has?

Tags: java, onenote

I tried JtextPane and one more that allows formatting, but I feel like things are very limited. Features I'd like to use are:

- Formatted text
- Hyperlinks
- Pictures
- Tables
- Math formulas
- Drawing
- Tags

Comment: Yes, the built-ins are somewhat limited. You're not going to find a full-blown, advanced, mixed-media, formatting editor in the standard JDK. You may find one in the wild by searching for it (and maybe pay for it), or write it yourself.

Comment: I agree. I'd like to write one myself. But not sure what's the right starting point. JTextPane, JEditorPane vs. HTMLEditorKit vs. something else